# Making an image using border-radius blurred causing the edges to not have border-radius

Tags: css, border-radius

I have an image that has a border-radius property and I want it to be blurred while hovering over it. But when I hover over it the blur applies but the border-radius property is not applied. How can I fix this?

I tried adding border-radius to different classes but none worked.

I'm not sure what code to share. Maybe this could be helpful. The .entry-thumbnail refers to the image post:

```
    .entry-thumbnail {

        position: relative;

        .entry-thumbnail:after {
            display: block;
            content: "";
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            z-index: 99;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity 200ms linear;
        }

    }

}

a:hover .entry-thumbnail:after {
    opacity: 1;
}

.secondary {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 101;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity 200ms linear;
}
a:hover .secondary, a.hover .secondary {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

What I added was this:

```
img {
    border-radius: 10px;
}

img:hover {
    -webkit-filter: blur(4px); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    filter: blur(10px);
}
```

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. If you want help with your code, it's impossible for anyone to help you if you don't show the code you want help with. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question. Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/77051587/edit) and add some code to your question.

Comment: @ChrisBarr I added some code but I am not sure if it's the correct part...

Comment: The way to know if it's correct or not is to add the relevant HTML and then see if the code you added reproduces what you are describing or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your blur is a bit strong, if you want to keep a clear border-radius, you have to wrap it in a container that has the border-radius and `overflow: hidden`

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;  
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
img {
  &:hover {
    filter: blur(5px);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://placehold.co/200x200" />
</div>
```

Comment: Adding 'overflow: hidden' and a border-radius to the class that the image was using fixed the issue. Thanks a lot for helping a noob out!

Comment: No worries, we all started somewhere ^^ Please mark the answer as accepted, if it solved your Problem